# HL7 Acknowledgement - can i have multiple ERR segment in acknowledgement message?

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

I was writing HL7 Acknowledgement mechanism on my own.

From the online documentation I followed, they state that a Hl7 acknowledgement message has following segments

```
MSH
MSA
ERR [ optional ]
```

And I am wondering - if there are multiple errors exists in HL7 file, can I put multiple ERR segments to describe each error? Is there any standard for this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

As of HL7 v2.5, you would put each error into its own ERR segment, populating field ERR-2-x (cf. ch 2.15.5 of the standard)
Before 2.5 you would have a single ERR segment and describe each error into its own repetition of the (repeatable) field ERR-1.